# How to deal with an error in CarouselView in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, carousel

I would like to know how to deal with an error in CarouselView in Xamarin.
I have written the following in Xaml and linked it to a group of photos.

```xml
            <CarouselView 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding PageImages}"
                          CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentPage}"
                          Position="{Binding CurrentPosition}"
                          >
                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PageImage" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

I am using ViemModel stopwatch to replace the photos in a slide show.

```
        private void OnStopWatchTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentPosition++;
        }
```

In this case, if the photos fail to load, the application crashes.
Where do I try-catch in the code to catch the error when the photos fail to load?

Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2337
Xamarin.Essentials 1.7.1

Comment: What is the error? Perhaps you are overflowing the index?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
The error has not been identified. I would like to know how to do try-catch.
I have hundreds of image files. The error may occur in about 10 of them, and it is unlikely to be beyond the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try the plugin : https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading .

Use [CachedImage](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#xaml) instead of built in `Image`, since it would display a default placeholder image if the load is failed ,so in this case it will not crash .

```
xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"

<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PageImage" >
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            WidthRequest="300" 
            HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source = Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
            LoadingPlaceholder = "loading.png" >
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I suggest, you stop suggesting this unmaintained library. Project is dead.

Comment: Thank you, ColeX.
I was able to get it working with FFImage.
If you can figure out the error, this is good enough for me.

Comment: CheeseBaron, thanks for your comment.
Is FFImage already out of maintenance?
If CarouselView doesn't work, and FFImage doesn't work, is there a better way?